# Dependent project cannot see headers from a library in refferences in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, header-files

I am learning how to make a static library. I started with windows and Visual Studio.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
 - MyLibraryProject
   - include
     - MyLibraryProject
       - MyLibraryHeader.h
   - src
     - MyLibrarySource.cpp
   - build
     - MyLibraryProject.vcxproj
 - MyDependentProject
   - main.cpp
   - MyDependentProject.vcxproj
```

`MyLibraryProject.vcxproj` has the following settings:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Configuration type | Static library (.lib) |
| Additional Include Directories | $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../include/MyLibraryProject |

`MyDependentProject.vcxproj` has no special settings, except I added `MyLibraryProject` onto refferences, the image features actual names I used:

[image]

If I use relative paths in main.cpp, I can build the project - the static linking works just fine and it runs:

```
#include "../MyLibraryProject/include/MyLibraryProject/MyLibraryHeader.h"
```

However, I want to include the headers like this:

```
// fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MyLibraryProject/MyLibraryHeader.h': No such file or directory
#include <MyLibraryProject/MyLibraryHeader.h>
```

And that just does not work. I also tried to use property sheet but couldn't get that to work either. I've been searching the internet, but generally found claims that if you add a reference, both headers and static libs will work.

Here's the [full repository](https://github.com/Darker/RawHTTP), if you're willing to take a look. Or ask in the comments if there's information missing.

Comment: @AndyG Updated. It cannot see the header, despite all the information I found says it should. Also, same approach is used at my work and it works fine. I tried to compare the projects at work but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project references do not provide the dependent project with any information about headers. The most flexible way to do this instead (in Visual Studio) are property sheets. I created a file `MyLibraryProject/build/MyLibraryProjectDependency.props`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

And I added it to `MyDependentProject.vcxproj` in Property explorer in Visual Studio. This solved the issues and headers are now seen on the path I want them.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Just FYI, self answers cannot be accepted any sooner than 2 days after they were posted, this is why you may often encounter self answers that are still not accepted.